# How to update a div value with js?

Tags: javascript, html, function

i need some help,

i need that only the selected template is displayed on the screen, and all others are removed, so the expected result should be that those values:
`<div class="city">City<span>,</span></div> <div class="country">Co</div>`
would be replaced from the selected template values.

In short, what I need to do is for the user to choose a city from all those shown and when they click on the desired city, js obtains the values ​​and shows them on the screen, removing all the other options.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks1mk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5GCR.png)

```js
const userLocationContainer = document.querySelector("[data-location-container]")
const locationTemplate = document.getElementById("location-template");

function setValue(selector, value, { parent = document } = {}) {
    parent.querySelector(`[data-${selector}]`).textContent = value
}


userLocationContainer.addEventListener('click', handleLocation);

function handleLocation(location) {
    const clonedTemplate = locationTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
    setValue("city", location.city, { parent: clonedTemplate });
    setValue("country", location.country, { parent: clonedTemplate });

    // Clear previous content of userLocation and append the cloned template
    
    userLocationContainer.innerHTML = '';
    selectedLocation.append(...clonedTemplate.childNodes);
}
```

```html
</div>
      <div class="locations" data-location-container>
        <div class="mainPlace" id="userLocation">
          <div class="city">City<span>,</span></div>
          <div class="country">Co</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <template id="location-template" data-location>
    <div class="mainPlace-template">
      <div class="city" data-city></div><span>,</span>
      <div class="country" data-country></div>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I converted your code into a runnable code snippet... however you have invalid HTML and no styles. It's really hard to figure out what you are trying to do were with the limited code you have provided. Please provide a complete and functional demo that reproduces the issue you are having.

Comment: if youre working with React on client side I would work with useState

Comment: @Savyon: And what indication do you have that they're using React?

Comment: Thats the 'if' part.

Comment: @Savyon: In that case you forgot to mention what they should do if they wanted to use Angular, or Vue, or Knockout, or jQuery, or anything else that they're not using and not asking about.  We can appreciate that React may be *your* favorite JavaScript tool, but there's little point in recommending it as a response to an unrelated question.

Comment: I saw your comment on Jatin's answer. Honestly you shouldn't be doing this in JavaScript. You should start by putting all your city information in a database, and use an App Engine to either display queries directly or to format query information in a way that you can use AJAX to load it dynamically from JavaScript/A webpage.

Answer (score 1):

There is a canonical way of doing this, which is to use a common class, and on click, hide all elements of that class and then show the selected one.

```js
var hide = (elem) => {
  elem.style.display = "none";
}

var hideNShow = (e) => {
  var cities = document.querySelectorAll(".city");
  cities.forEach(hide);
  document.getElementById("City_" + e.target.value).style.display = "block";
}

document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]").forEach((elem) => elem.addEventListener("click", hideNShow));
```

```html
<input type="button" value="A" />
<input type="button" value="B" />
<input type="button" value="C" />
<input type="button" value="D" />

<div id="City_A" class="city">City A</div>
<div id="City_B" class="city">City B</div>
<div id="City_C" class="city">City C</div>
<div id="City_D" class="city">City D</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you need kind of this feature (assuming that you need dropdown as mentioned users will choose)

```html
<body>
  <div class="locations" data-location-container>
    <div class="mainPlace" id="userLocation">
      <div class="city">City<span>,</span></div>
      <div class="country">Co</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <select id="locationDropdown" onchange="handleLocation(this)">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select a City</option>
    <option value="City1,Country1">City1</option>
    <option value="City2,Country2">City2</option>
    <!-- Add more options as needed -->
  </select>

  <template id="location-template" data-location>
    <div class="mainPlace-template">
      <div class="city" data-city></div><span>,</span>
      <div class="country" data-country></div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    function handleLocation(selectedDropdown) {
      const locationContainer = document.querySelector('[data-location-container]');
      const locationTemplate = document.getElementById('location-template');
      const clonedTemplate = locationTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);

      const selectedOption = selectedDropdown.options[selectedDropdown.selectedIndex];
      if (!selectedOption || !selectedOption.value) {
        return; // No valid selection
      }

      const [city, country] = selectedOption.value.split(',');

      setValue("city", city, { parent: clonedTemplate });
      setValue("country", country, { parent: clonedTemplate });

      // Clear previous content of userLocation and append the cloned template
      locationContainer.innerHTML = '';
      locationContainer.append(...clonedTemplate.childNodes);

      // Reset the dropdown to the default state
      selectedDropdown.selectedIndex = 0;
    }

    function setValue(key, value, options) {
      const element = options.parent.querySelector(`[data-${key}]`);
      if (element) {
        element.innerText = value;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is what is closest to what I need, what happens is that I do not have a specific number of cities, that is, through an input, city data is requested from an API, so the number of templates that They will vary depending on the coincidence of what the user is writing. What I want to do is a search bar to select a certain city.

Comment: @Wayfarerdesert, on the response, whenever data is requested, you can map the city data to the dropdown